# how to solve problem with loading large amount of data in django?

Tags: python, django, autocomplete, frameworks, large-data

I'm trying to write an app like IMDb for my work project. In this app, I need to store 8700 IMDB movies and also about 40k directors and actors/actresses in MySQL database,

When I was trying to post a new movie, the movie creation page took a long time (about 20s) to render.

first, I made a model named "persons" with person name, gender, "is_director" and "is_actor" boolean fields.

then, I created a model named "movies" with 2 ManyToManyFields for is_director and is_actor persons.

after that, I imported about 40k persons to my database with Django fixture.
my problem started from here. when I was trying to post a new movie from Django admin, the movie creation page took a long time (about 10s) to render.
I know this is for a large amount of persons data. I did use Django built-in autocomplete but the problem was still there.

I'm new to Python/Django. so I think I'm doing this in a wrong way.
maybe my database structure is wrong or my model has a problem, I don't know how to solve it!

```
# Person Model:
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_('Person Name'), max_length=100)
    is_actor = models.BooleanField(_('is actor'), default=True)
    is_director = models.BooleanField(_('is director'), default=False)
    MALE = 'male'
    FEMALE = 'female'
    PERSON_GENDER = [(MALE, _('Male')), (FEMALE, _('Female'))]
    gender = models.CharField(
        _('Gender'),
        max_length=6,
        choices=PERSON_GENDER,
        default=MALE
    )

# Movies Model:
class Movies(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(_('Movie Name'), max_length=250)
    genre = models.ManyToManyField(Genre, verbose_name=_('genre'))
    director = models.ManyToManyField(
        Person, verbose_name=_('director'), related_name=_('director'),limit_choices_to={'is_director': True},blank=True)
    actors = models.ManyToManyField(
        Person, verbose_name=_('actors'), related_name=_('actors'),limit_choices_to={'is_actor': True},blank=True)
```

1- Is there a problem with my code?

2- Am I doing this in a wrong way?

3- Have I picked the wrong framework?

4- I'm Familiar with asp.net core and Laravel. Is it better to write this kind of app with them? language is no problem, I only need performance.

Comment: Is it slow if you add a movie without loading the fixture data?

Comment: I am not familiar to django but a general approach when dealing with large amount of data.

1- Pagination
2- Eager loading/ Lazy loading 
3- Use serializers to restrict useless data attributes

These are few things that I did in my project. (Angularjs + Rails)

Comment: If you do not use Pagination, memoization, caching behaviour does not matter which technology you use (If you have so big data). There are the largest  web-apps written in Django (instagram, disqus, bitbucket, pinterest, disqus and so on). Django scales. Use pagination and load data dynamically onscroll, this is always good idea (Mostly web-apps are implemented this way). Data is never loaded at once.

Comment: dear Will, it loads the page in a few milliseconds without it.

Comment: in the admin page django creates a multi select field. there is no pagination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your admin page contains your 40k persons list twice.
Try to use *raw_id_fields* in the admin for your director and actors fields.

Please see [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.raw_id_fields)
and [this article about very long list](https://ponytech.net/blog/admin-interface-with-foreign-key-on-a-very-long-list) (with an example with *ForeignKey* but it should also work with *ManyToManyField*)